# Security of regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, security

Say that I want to let a user input whichever regular expression he wants, and a string to match, and I will check whether it matches using Python's `re.compile`. Is that secure? Is there a way for a malicious user to crash or get remote execution by passing in specially-crafted strings?

Comment: As a side-note, depending your needs, maybe worth considering a simple _glob_ expression, rather than full-fledged regex. For most user it is easier to understand. And it will require much less power to process. But again, it will depend on your needs...

Answer (score 9):

I don't think that `re.compile()` is going to be a problem. Of course it can throw an exception with invalid regexes, but you can easily catch those. Python regexes don't allow code callouts (unlike Perl, for example), so I don't see a mechanism that an attacker could use to inject malicious code into a regex.

Actually running the regex (via `re.search()` etc.) can be a problem, though, because Python doesn't take any precautions against [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) which may cause the regex's runtime to skyrocket.

It may be a good idea to run the regex in a dedicated process and kill that if it doesn't finish within a second or so.